# How to inform the employer about delays in obtaining the necessary documentation

Tags: documentation

I have to write a formal mail to my employer and I  need to advise my employer that there were some delays with the documents requested. I would like to inform him that I am trying to get the certificate before my leaving (because I am currently out of the country) and otherwise I have to wait until that the custom office will send it to me in a week. I've be trying to write it in this way.

> There were delays with the Birth certificate, maybe I am going to get it tomorrow before my leaving or they will send it to me in a week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with hairy (sensitive) personal information and pertaining necessary documentation like this are better sorted out via a phone call, or better yet, in person. Since in person is out of the question, try a phone call. Be honest.

If it has to be a email write something like this:

> Greetings $employer,
>
> Due to administrative issues with obtaining my birth certificate, I am
>   sadly unable to provide it to you until $date. I hope this is
>   acceptable to you. If you have inquiries or issues regarding this,
>   feel free to message me.
>
> $yourname

Things about writing an email:

- Be concise
- Be honest
- Don't sugarcoat reality.